# python3.3 bubble sort: returning None if list already sorted

Tags: python

i write a buuble sort alrogithm to sort out a list of tuples by the integer part.

but i would like to return None if the given list is already sorted. how would i do this?

```
def bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list):

    NEWLIST = []
    for i in tuples_list:
        NEWLIST.append(i)
    for i in range(len(NEWLIST)):
         for j in range(i+1, len(NEWLIST)):
             if(NEWLIST[j][1]<NEWLIST[i][1]):
                 NEWLIST[j],NEWLIST[i] = NEWLIST[i],NEWLIST[j]


    print(NEWLIST)

tuples_list = [("h1",1),("h2",2),("h3", 3), ("hi" , 4)]

bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list)
```

Comment: You are returning `None` for _all_ cases already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to check if the list is sorted before sorting it. I wouldn't see any other easier solution than this.

Or check if any item was moved like this:

```
def bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list):

    NEWLIST = []
    itemMoved=0
    for i in tuples_list:
        NEWLIST.append(i)
    for i in range(len(NEWLIST)):
         for j in range(i+1, len(NEWLIST)):
             if(NEWLIST[j][1]<NEWLIST[i][1]):
                 itemMoved=1
                 NEWLIST[j],NEWLIST[i] = NEWLIST[i],NEWLIST[j]

    if(itemMoved==0): print("None")
    else: print(NEWLIST)

tuples_list = [("h1",1),("h2",2),("h3", 3), ("hi" , 4)]

bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list)
```

Comment: thanks alot guys. the ItemMoved works perfectly. the one with the False also is great:) we didnt study lambda functions yet farhad.. so this will have to wait untill i have better understanding of these.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you change the array 
and return it only if it were changed:

```
def bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list):
    edited = False
    newlist = []
    for i in tuples_list:
        newlist.append(i)
        for i in range(len(newlist)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(newlist)):
                if (newlist[j][1]<newlist[i][1]):
                    edited = True
                newlist[j], newlist[i] = newlist[i], newlist[j]
    if edited:
       return newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tuples_list = [("h1",1),("h2",2),("h3", 3), ("hi" , 4)]
sorted(tuples_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if a list is sorted with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def is_sorted(list_):
    result = True
    for element1, element2 in zip(list_, list_[1:]):
        if element1 <= element2:
            # this pair compares favorably
            pass
        else:
            result = False
            break

    return result
```

However, if this isn't an academic exercise, you probably should use something like sorted(list_, key=operator.itemgetter(1)) - because it's easier, and because Python's built-in sorting is really quite good.

HTH